# Install ansible 2.5 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-22.04

I'd like to install Ansible 2.5 in Ubuntu 22.04, because our deployment playbook incompatible with Ansible newer version. I tried installing from apt, but ppa doesn't provide 2.5 for 22.04. Installing by pip also not work as well.
can someone shed some light on this please

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks, I just post this question on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

**Please read this first**

---

This is an extremely bad idea as ansible 2.5 was released in 2018 which is ages ago in ansible release pace context. As a consequence:

1. you will have to run that version of ansible on the controller in python 2.7 which is also deprecated
2. you will probably have to fight with bugs that have already been fixed for months or even years.

From my experience, unless you are in a very particular situation, the effort it takes to update your playbooks is quite low compared to the gain you will get running the latest Ansible version and filling you technical debt gap.

---

That being said, I was able to install ansible 2.5 in minutes in an ubuntu 22.04 docker image. Given my remarks above, I actually suggest you run your outdated version of ansible isolated from the rest of your system in a docker container if you really do not want to update your playbooks.

Here is the full test install session (without output for the install commands which is too long and irrelevant). You can transport all this inside a Dockerfile if you want to create an image for your own needs.

I started a trashable test container from my host:

```bash
docker run -it --rm ubuntu:22.04 bash
```

Then inside the container:

```bash
apt update
apt install -y python-pip
pip2 install "ansible<2.6"
```

And now we can check ansible is correctly installed. Please note the `python2/cryptography` warnings which relate to my preliminary comments above...

```
$ ansible --version
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py:44: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.
  from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature
ansible 2.5.15
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.18 (default, Jul  1 2022, 10:30:50) [GCC 11.2.0]
```